# Wrong data type for _mm_rsqrt_pd()?

Tags: c, intrinsics

I'm new to these Intrinsics but was wondering if you could help me out. My program won't compile because of this error. Any ideas on how to fix it? I would assume that this should work because r2_v is also of data type __m128d

```
error: initializing '__m128d' (vector of 2 'double' values)
with an expression of incompatible type 'int'
                    __m128d r2inv_v = _mm_rsqrt_pd(r2_v);
                            ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Thanks.

This is the code it errors around

```
__m128d r2_v = _mm_add_pd(_mm_add_pd(_mm_mul_pd(rx_v, rx_v),_mm_mul_pd(ry_v, ry_v)),_mm_add_pd(_mm_mul_pd(rz_v, rz_v),eps_v));
__m128d r2inv_v = _mm_rsqrt_pd(r2_v);
```

Comment: The error without the code is not a lot of help.  It looks like you are trying to use an integer where it takes a vector of doubles -Take a look at https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#cats=Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a variable of the type `__m128d`. You can create one using

> `__m128d _mm_set_pd (double e1, double e0)`

or use it directly in the call

```
_mm_rsqrt_pd( _mm_set_pd( d1, d2 ) );
```